# What relay do I need

Tags: relay

Hello friendly friends.

In my wood shop I have two separate 220V circuits, A and B. B is new and I want to use it to drive the dust collection (1800W). Now I want it so that when I power on one of the machines (1500W+) driven by circuit A the dust collector will power on too.

Simple, I thought, just buy a relay and hook it up. So I bought an Eltako R12-100-230V relay (See amazon, I cant put a link in here). 
I then connected the phase wire of A trough connectors A1 and A2 and the phase wire of the dust collection to 1 and 2.

Alas it doesnt work. Instead when I power on a machine, the relay will click and cut the power of A!???

I am now unsure wether I use the wrong relay or hooked it up wrongly.

This is what I have:

[image]

And If I understand NMF++ from the comments below right then this is what I should do:

[image]

Here's what I have atm:

[image]

Comment: A schematic of what you've got at the moment would help with understanding what is happening.

Comment: If you've put A in series with the relay coil (via A1 and A2), then the coil resistance will prevent A from receiving sufficient current. Effectively you need to connect the relay coil in parallel with A so that it is energised when A is switched on but doesn't affect the supply to A.

Comment: I see, that is a sensible explanation. I will try that tomorrow. But speaking of running things in parallel; while cramming two pieces of wire in one end of a lustre terminal - and that's all I have atm - technically works, what is the proper way / connector technique of doing so?

Comment: @PhilG I added schematics.

Comment: @Holli I understand better what you're trying to do from your schematic. For it to work as desired you'd need to connect A1 to the switched phase (inside the machine) and A2 to neutral. Alternatively you could use an external 
switch to turn the machine on/off and connect A1 to the switched side of that (and A2 to neutral)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright. I ended up buying the KEMO M103N for 20 Euros which is basically a master/slave circuit in a box with a bunch of connector wires and does what I want. Thanks everybody.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi7n5q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) What you did. (b) What you intended.*

Relay coils have a high resistance relative to your motor load. When wired in series as in Figure 1a the relay finds it's 'neutral' connection through the load. Its high resistance lets a small current through and this isn't enough to start the motor. If you put an AC voltmeter across the motor you would only read a few volts.

Wiring the relay in parallel with the load as shown in Figure 1b will give the desired result. Both the relay and the motor have a live and a neutral connection.

---

The ASCII schematics were a noble attempt although they might be clearer using | - and + characters.

```
N     P
|     |
|     |
|     +----+ A1   | 1
|     |   +++     |
|     |   | |      /
|     |   | |     /
|     |   +++     |
+----------+ A2   | 2
|     |
+-( )-+
```

Even better, there is a CircuitLab schematic button on the editor toolbar!

Comment: So, in terms of wiring: I connect brown to A1 AND to brown, and blue to A2 AND also to blue, am I right?

Comment: I've coloured the wiring for you.

Comment: Yes, that's how I understood it. Thank you and everybody else for your time.

Comment: Today I wired things up like you said, it still doesnt work. The relay now closes the switch as soon as it gets connected to the mains, where it should only close it when there is current flowing aka a machine is turned on. Hang on, I'll post a picture when my phone is charged up again.

Comment: That's a slightly different requirement than suggested by your question. I have shown the relay wired *after* the power switch of the load to be monitored. You seem to want to detect before the switch so you would need a **current sensing relay** with the correct rating. (You have purchased a voltage sensing relay.) The current sensing relay could then be wired in series as shown in Figure 1a (which is as you supposed originally). Can you add the relay inside your machine?

Answer (score 0):

For a machine on circuit A to to be able to swich circuit you'd need to connect your relay, which has a coil that operates at 230V, across the motor in that machine - after all the isolators and switches that allow it to operate.

If you have machines (plural) on circuit A, to be able to switch circuit B when any of them are on, you'd need a relay for each machine, with the coils wired across the motors on each one, and then connect the contacts all in parallel - a relay OR gate - which are then wired into circuit B as you indicate.

There are current-sensing relays, that you could use, which would switch on when any of the machines on A were turned on. These would be wired exactly how you have the original arrangement, though most high current ones rely not on a direct connection through sense terminals, but on either current transformers or Hall current sensors so that you only need to loop one of the live wires through the core to operate it.
[image]

Comment: @Transistor Progress, tyvm. Can you advice me further in which relay to buy? The Eltako AR12DX-230V seems to be capable, but way too expensive. Unless there arent cheaper ones in the 15 Euro range, I guess I just go second best and buy a remote controlled switch for the dust collector.

Comment: Theses electronic current sense relays are necessarily more complex and expensive than the simple electromechanical relays. There are far cheaper current-sensing relays used in motor starting that are purely electromechanical, but these are only short term rated, so wouldn't work for what you're doing. The issue with current sensing is that if you need to have enough power available from the sensing element to operate a relay, it's necessarily going to dissipate that power all the time. Electronic ones rely on a very small signal from the sensing element, which is then amplified.