# Current sensing relay with delay on break for dust collection system

Tags: solid-state-relay, delay, current-sensing

I am in the process of planning our a new workshop in a single car garage.  I have a large 20A Dust Collector that needs to be on its own circuit or else it will trip.  I also have a ceiling mounted air cleaner to get any fine particles that get airborne.

I want to setup a system where if I turn on any of my individually switched tools such as my Table Saw the air systems will turn on automatically and remain on for some time  after. I also have them switched so that they can turn on manually.

As a lowly Civil Engineer I'm a little bit out of my depth clearly, but I tried to do a schematic for this.  Can you gentleman tell me if I am on the right track?

I also made an album with some parts pulled from Amazon for the project.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFHc0.jpg

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw1Y45.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Your schematic shows all the switches directly shorting across the loads when they are closed. Something has to change here.

Comment: How many outlets are "Any tools"

Comment: 1) As I said I’m not that familiar with drawing circuit diagrams. I will look into what you said about the switches.

Comment: I would improve the dust collection system with a higher velocity Central +Vac. air flow system (not higher volume) then a Thrush muffler on the ABS exhaust. Then a quiet HEPA air circulator with deionizer running all the time or all the time with lights on or with a timer. This is low power.  A current sensor around garage breaker wires can be used to activate a   Relay card off the shelf with isolation to power the Central Vac in garage. with a spring valve to close so it can be used for house vac.  This is a better Mech Eng solution

Comment: 2) Will be quite a few wall outlets. Maybe 10

Comment: As an EE with CE and ME experience, I look at 5" or 6" high impedance pipes  , smart angle air splitters then https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=--n04W78_3I  only transform high 500~1000 CFM to high velocity with a tapered pipe as close as possible to the extraction point to get extremely high velocity intake with a straight plenem to avoid edge (eddy current) noise.  THEN use up to 6 stage filters. For the same reason you double sandpaper 100 200 400 800 1600 3200 and NOT 1 or 2 stage. Same for  an aggregate dam.

Comment: So use a 2 stage Cyclone then 4 stage filters and truck exhaust pipe or outside to make it quiet.  SO modify your poor 20A Dust Collector

Comment: Curious how often questions about dust collection systems come up - there's a few to be found with a search.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/403250/what-relay-do-i-need

Comment: Matt The Turbine separates the dust into a bin rather than clog the filter https://youtu.be/e7kpogfLjRw?t=584

Comment: @Phil G The issue is most people posting these questions probably need a little bit more help than the average user. I did search and read a bunch of them, but nothing fully explained my confusion.

Comment: @Tony I modified my dust collector already to be 2 stage with a cyclone. I plan on ordering a better filter bag as well. All good suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Using a large 8" duct then tapering down to small plenum within 1/2 diameter from   dust+chip source is like transforming 100V to 1kV in voltage equal to air velocity. It will zap everything then a good Cyclone is like high Q resonant velocity amplifier., Smooth metal is best for static elimination with no sharp corners like microwave. Most PC towers have terrible  fan designs just circulating and making noise, Instead of eddy current high velocity near source then inline plenum fan to exhaust.  Never put fans against grills,rather inline plenum , just like turbine dust collectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your topology is super wonky. Here is what you are looking for. Also, the time delay relay you chose won't do what you want. This or something similar is the relay that you want.

[https://www.amazon.com/Liukouu-GRT8-B1-Power-Delay-12V-240V/dp/B07VB9BMZL/ref=sr_1_5?keywords=delay+off+relay&qid=1579709274&s=home-garden&sr=1-5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VB9BMZL)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKkksR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Beautiful!  I was really unsure of how the 2 relays would be drawn in a schematic. I can see now based on what you did how far off I was. Putting the two fans with the indicator light in parallel on a single power source makes much more sense.  I also wasnt sure how to distinguish between a power source and a "Load".

Comment: @Matt Not sure if I accurately portrayed how the current sensing switch is wired. It may be self-powered. Then you would just omit the two connections on top.

Comment: They are sold both ways. I’ll figure it out based on which one I purchase